# How to extract text in an area using x & y coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, pdf.js

I am using PDFJS to render a PDF, as well as extract its text into a text layer.

I also have a tool to draw a box over this PDF which outputs me x, y, width, and height coordinates of the selection.

Now, I would like to be able to extract the text from the selected area referencing my coordinates and the text layer. Does PDFJS have any way of extracting text by coordinates? Or is there any other means I am overlooking?

I appreciate any help you can provide.